# Deep Learning: First Loss in Epoch Should be $-\log(1/C)$?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I found the following introductory slides on deep learning https://www2.cisl.ucar.edu/sites/default/files/0900%20June%2023%20Kashinath.pdf

On slide 61, there is a practical tips that says:

> [...] if you are using a negative log-likelihood for a $10$-classes classification problem you expect your first loss to be $\sim -\log\left(1/C\right) = -\log\left(1/10\right) \approx 2.3$

(Note that $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm.)

My question is:

**Assuming that we are starting from randomly initialized weights (an assumption that is also made on the slide), how can we prove that we expect the first loss to be around $-\ln(C^{-1})$, where $C$ denotes the number of classes?**

Comment: The slide said that if you are using a negative log-likelihood. The **negative log-likelihood** is a loss function, and it is defined from its name. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) to learn more about the likelihood function.

Comment: Thanks. I observed in trainings with a residual network that the loss after the first batch has a value of around $2.6$ **without** weight decay, which is a kind of regularization. Would you have an explanation for this?

Comment: What is your defined loss function?

Comment: It is cross entropy, cf. here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html So basically softmax and the negative log likelihood, but the softmax function should **not** have an effect on what value our loss should have in the first batch because of the random weight initialization...

Comment: @Tab1e Any comments on the residual layers?